# Can't see the adapterArray information on listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, broadcast

I have a problem. I try to show some information on a listView, I use an ArrayAdapter, but I can't see anything. I put the code below, I hope it helps:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayList<String> arrayFinal = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < idRocodromo.size(); i++)
{
    arrayFinal.add(idRocodromo.get(i) + " - " + rocodromo.get(i) + " - " + ciudad.get(i) + " - " + comentario.get(i));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayFinal);


listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

ArrayFinal has info, but it's not showed on the listView, can anyone help me? It could be because it is on a BroadcastReciever?

Comment: prolly because idRocodromo is empty at the time of Adapter's creation

Comment: For one listview needs to be declared as ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: no, arrayFinal has info, I wrote it on my question. And i see it, and also idRocodromo, rocodromo, ciudad y comentario have info

Comment: @JordanSeanor sorry, I copied the code uncorrectly, I have the listview declared as you say, excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to complete what you are trying to do is to create your own custom ListView adapter. I imagine from your code what you are trying to do is add strings from your arraylist to a ListView that you can look at later.

The nice thing about a custom adapter is that you control everything in the ListView views and can display exactly what you want in a much more finite way. Below is a VERY VERY basic example of completing this.

**Main Activity XML**

You can see all we are doing in this layout file is declaring a listview to live inside of our Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Single Row XML**

For the single view we can get as complex or simple as we'd like. Here I have only added in a TextView but you can add in images, sounds, buttons, honestly whatever your heart desires!.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

This class is simply for initializations and creating of our data. I tried to simulate your arrays as best as possible but this is not in any way the best way to generate them or set them up, but if you are sure your data is correct than this will work just fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList mainArr,arrOne, arrTwo;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, configureList());
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    public ArrayList configureList(){
        arrOne = new ArrayList();
        arrTwo = new ArrayList();
        mainArr = new ArrayList();
        arrOne.add(0, "Joe");
        arrOne.add(1, "Phil");
        arrOne.add(2, "Jose");
        arrTwo.add(0, "Mexico City");
        arrTwo.add(1, "Minneapolis");
        arrTwo.add(2, "Pittsburgh");

        for(int i = 0; i < arrOne.size(); i++){
            mainArr.add(i, arrOne.get(i) + " - " + arrTwo.get(i));
        }
        return  mainArr;
     }
}
```

**Custom Adapter**

This is the place where we will really create our new adapter. This adapter is how we will generate and format our ListView with the data and information. When you initally create this class you will auto-generate several methods that are important. Arguably the getView method is probably one of the most important in this class. This is where you are actually setting up your individual rows and views!

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList myData;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList data){
        this.myData = data;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    //I tell you how big and how many rows are going to be in the listview.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myData.size();
    }

    //I will return the object at an exact posiition in the listview.
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    /*
    I create and configure the views for you! You can see here that we are taking a view, inflating it to our single row
    that we created earlier and then we can reference the textview or whatever else we want!
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.single_row, null);
    }
    TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setText(myData.get(position).toString());
    return view;
    }
}
```

This would be the best way IMO to create your listview as it gives you more control and functionality. You can easily scale your application this way as well because you just need to adjust this class with whatever other images or whatnot that you want.

**Resources**

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/